# PayPal REST API: When do I get the approved state for payments over a PayPal account?

Tags: paypal

When I process a payment via the REST API (using the PayPal REST SDK for .NET) I first create a payment

```
Payment payment = ...
Payment createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
```

I store the ID of the created payment for later use. Then I redirect to the provided payment page. In the page that PayPal calls after the user approved tha payment I want to get information about the payment.

I call

```
Payment payment = Payment.Get(apiContext, paymentID);
```

using the stored payment ID.

I expected the state of the payment beeing 'approved' here but it is still 'created'.

What could be wrong? When or how do I get the 'approved' state?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. You need to

   > construct a payment object with *payment id* and use the *payer id* **returned** from PayPal and make the API call using the access token.

   That is the query params returned from the *SuccesUrl* you provided when redirecting to paypal.
   e.g

   > http://yourserver.com/payment/paypal/success.asp?payerid=EC-43242423&token=FS321-DFSD-3123DFS-3G243
2. Then

   > Execute a payment:

   ```
   Payment payment = new Payment("");
   PaymentExecution pymntExecution = new PaymentExecution();
   pymntExecution.payer_id = ("");
   Payment executedPayment = pymnt.Execute(apiContext,pymntExecution);
   ```
3. See step 4 / 5 from paypal tutorial:

   https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/dotnet?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox

**Edit by Jürgen Bayer**

I accept this answer but I just add a few things I found out with the help of the PayPal support:

- `created` results after a payment was created. It is still the state after the payer authorized the payment (that was my error in reasoning: `approved` does not mean "approved by the payer" but "approved by PayPal". There is no state for "authorized").
- After a payment was executed the state can be `pending`, `approved`, `failed`, `cancelled` or `expired`
- `pending` means that PyPal has to perform some security checks or that the payment is a bank transfer. In the latter PayPal must wait until the bank transfer was completed.
- `approved` means that the payment was approved by PayPal. This state can result with credit card payments.
- `failed`: According to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB04C0HS this state results if the payment is a bank transfer that could not be completed, for example because the bank account had not enough funds.
- `cancelled`: The payment was canceled  (question is though, by whom?)
- `expired`: The payment authorization has expired and could not be captured.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's what I already do and it does not answer my question (when do I get the approved state?). After creating the payment, redirecting to PayPal and beeing redirected from PayPal to the return_url I provided, I fetch the payment from PayPal (payment = Payment.Get(apiContext, paymentID)). The state in the resulting Payment object is still 'created'. I expect the state beeing 'approved' (in case the customer approved the payment).

Comment: The payment is approved *only* after pynment.execute(). Before that, you have an approval to take transfer the funds and you can still choose whether to claim the funds or not.

Comment: Where did you get that? It seems a bit weird since for me the meaning of 'approved' is, well, 'approved', and that's exactly what the payer did before PayPal redirects to the confirmation page (if the payer cancels PayPal redirects to the cancel URL). I admit that 'approved' in some cases results after executing a payment, but in other cases the resulting state is 'pending' (as I would expect). I begin to assume that PayPal has some timing issues, probably because payment changes are handled asynchronically. Probably we should not care about the state at all ...

Comment: See here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/#execute-the-payment

Comment: I cannot find anything on that page thas says something about the state of the payment after approval or after execution. And: I got a reply to a question about that from the PayPal merchant support. It states that 'approved' should result after the payer approved the payment. After executing the payment either 'pending' or (unkown to me) 'completed' should result. I get into it (I contact the technical support as suggeseted by the merchant support) and post my findings asap.

Comment: I'm seeing "approved" but in paypal I see "pending" and the money isn't in my account. What's wrong? This answer says I have to use GetTransactionDetails or something to solve this. True? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835993/paypal-api-pending-payments

Answer (score 1):

for node.js...

You need to call execute to update the status to approve

```
var execute_payment_json = {
    "payer_id": "Appended to redirect url",
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "1.00"
        }
    }]
};

var paymentId = 'PAYMENT id created in previous step';

paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("Get Payment Response");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's written there: "If the call is successful, we’ll return a confirmation of the transaction with the state being created."